# Prove that a continuous homogenous function of degree 0 is constant

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
let $f: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R , f$ is continuous s.t.
$\forall t>0: f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$ prove that f is constant.

**Thought**
it's very intuitive. We thought about sequences, about the definition of continuity, but didn't get very far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $t \to 0^+$, $(tx, ty) \to (0, 0)$ for any $x, y$. Hence by a sequential characterization of continuity,

$$f(x, y) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} f(tx, ty) = f(0, 0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take lim $t\rightarrow 0$ ... $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)\rightarrow f(0x,0y)=f(0,0)$.