# Proving a degree $0$ homogeneous function: $f: \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb R , f$ is constant? (notice the domain)

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb R $, such that:

$f$ a homogeneous function of degree $0$ (so that $\forall t>0: f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$),

$f$ is differentiable and positive in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

I would like to prove it is constant (this may not be true, but if it is it would help me prove some other statement I'm working on), but I'm having trouble doing so. In particular, because of the domain I cannot see how to use the $t\to 0$ argument that appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628394/prove-that-a-continuous-homogenous-function-of-degree-0-is-constant), since the function is not defined at $0$.

I thought of extending $f$ to some other function that *is* defined at $0$, but I'm not sure how. Also, some intuitive indication that what I'm trying to prove may be incorrect is imagining a 'volcano-like function' that goes to infinity at $(0,0)$ which wouldn't be constant (but I don't have a formula for it).

Even if it is not constant, might there be some simple construct for it that could be obtained (that might help me too)? **The reason I want this is to identify what the rank of the gradient is (when viewed as a matrix), and if it's $0$ to claim that it is a constant.**

Comment: mhmm, $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ seems to satisfy your constraint but is not constant, isn't it?

Comment: What about $x^2/(x^2 + y^2)$? (A few seconds late, oops)

Comment: As for your other problem, if I remember correctly only the $0$ matrix has rank $0$.

Comment: @Surb Thanks for the example, but I now realize that it doesn't satisfy the positivity requirement (e.g. for $(0,1)$).

Comment: @Anon Well, then take $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}$. You can easily construct further examples on $\Bbb R^n$ with $n\geq 2$, by considering $f(u)=\frac{\|u\|_{\alpha}}{\|u\|_{\beta}}$ where $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha},\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ are any two, distinct, differentiable norms on $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$. There are many, many more I think :).